# Approximation of a function in $L^2$ by functions with bounded reciprocals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f \in L^2(0,1)$.
Can one construct a sequence $\{f_\epsilon\}_{\epsilon>0} \subset L^2(0,1)$ such that

1. $f_\epsilon \longrightarrow f$ strongly in $L^2(0,1)$ as $\epsilon \longrightarrow 0$;
2. $\frac{1}{\epsilon} f_\epsilon$ is bounded in $L^2(0,1)$ for all $\epsilon>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(\frac1\epsilon f_\epsilon)$ is bounded in $L^2$, i.e., there exists $M>0$ such that $\epsilon^{-1} \|f_\epsilon\|_{L^2} \le M$, then necessarily $f_\epsilon \to0$ in $L^2$.